# how to obtain or retrieve the typed value inside load dash's debounce method in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, debouncing

How to obtain the input entered during the @typing event of the b-autocomplete component of buefy?

The debounce method is invoked with explicit parameters during the @typing event like this-

```
<b-field label="Location">
      <b-autocomplete
        :data="dataLocation"
        placeholder="select a location..."
        field="id"
        :loading="isFetching"
        :value="this.objectData.location"
        @typing="getAsyncData(`location`,`?filter= UPPER({id}) LIKE UPPER('%25${name}%25') OR UPPER({description}) LIKE UPPER('%25${name}%25')`)"
        @input="(newValue) => {updateValue(newValue,'location')}"
      >
        <template slot-scope="props">
          <div class="container">
            <p>
              <b>ID:</b>
              {{props.option.id}}
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Description:</b>
              {{props.option.description}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </template>
        <template slot="empty">No results found</template>                
      </b-autocomplete>
    </b-field>
```

debounce function

```
   getAsyncData: debounce(function(name,entity,queryparam) {
                console.log('event.target'+event.target)
                console.log('name is'+name)
                console.log('entity is'+entity)
                console.log('queryparam is'+queryparam)
                if (!name.length) {
                  this.data = [];
                  return;
                }
                this.isFetching = true;
                api
                  .getSearchData(this.sessionData.key,`/${entity}/${queryparam} `)
                  .then(response => {
                    this.data = [];
                    response.forEach(item => {
                       
                      this.data.push(item);
                    });
                   
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                    this.data = [];
                    throw error;
                  })
                  .finally(() => {
                    this.isFetching = false;
                  });
              }, 500),
```

In the above code the 'name' parameter inside the debounce function is not capturing the input during the @typing event.However it works when the debounce function is invoked without any parameters like this-

```
 @typing="getAsyncData"
```

But since iam trying to make the debounce function as a generic function i will need to explicity pass in parameters to the function so that nothing is hardcoded.Plz help?

Comment: What do you mean by " 'name' parameter inside the debounce function is not capturing the input during the @typing event"? You have hardcoded 'location'. Why should there be anything else?

Comment: ok . Normally when we invoke this method without any parameters, that time the  name variable captures the input entered into the textfield.(This is the default behaviour)

Comment: my question is how do we capture the input that the user enters into the textbox inside the debounce function when it is invoked by explicity specifying parameters?

Comment: have you read the docs? The `$event` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`@typing="getAsyncData('location','?filter= UPPER({id}) LIKE UPPER('%25${name}%25') OR UPPER({description}) LIKE UPPER('%25${name}%25')')"`

...is handling event by *inline statement* (the code is executed as-is). You need to pass original event to your method by yourself like this:

`@typing="getAsyncData($event, 'location','?filter= UPPER({id}) LIKE UPPER('%25${name}%25') OR UPPER({description}) LIKE UPPER('%25${name}%25')')"`

When using just method name (`@typing="getAsyncData"`), Vue does this automatically...

Comment: ok after passing the event object like this how to we get the input value that the user has typed? is it event.target.value?

Comment: Well it depends on the component.. For native `<input>` elements, it's `event.target.value`. For `b-autocomplete` you should check [the documentation](https://buefy.org/documentation/autocomplete/#api-view)